# Returning information from database through django to UI

Tags: python, html, django

Can anyone tell me why information is not being displayed in my html?

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/")
def userprofile(request):
    data = UserProfile.objects.all()
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'personalInfo/details.html', {"data": data})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^details/$', views.userprofile, name='patient'),
]
```

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fullName = models.CharField(max_length = 250, default='', blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 250, default='', blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 250, default='', blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True)
    homePhone = models.CharField(max_length = 250, default='', blank=True)
    personalPhone = models.CharField(max_length = 250, default='', blank=True)
    emergencyContact = models.CharField(max_length = 250, default='', blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 250, default='', blank=True)
    ppsn = models.CharField(max_length = 250, default='', blank=True)
    maritalStatus = models.CharField(max_length = 250, default='', blank=True)
    employment = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    personalPic = models.CharField(max_length = 250, default='', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.fullName + ' - ' + self.ppsn
```

I am using `{{ userprofile.fullbame }}` to return the name of the person. I am also using profiles with a one to one link to each user. 
What I want to happen is when a user is logged in that his own information is displayed of course like a profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@login_required(login_url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/")
def userprofile(request):
    data = UserProfile.objects.all()
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'personalInfo/details.html', {"data": data})
```

This is fetching *all* user profiles. You could loop through them with:

```
{% for profile in data %}
  {{ profile.fullName }}
{% endfor %}
```

However it looks as if you want to display the profile for the logged-in user. To do this you need to change the view to:

```
# it's tidier to leave out `login_url` here, and add LOGIN_URL to your settings if required
@login_required
def userprofile(request):
    profile = request.user.userprofile
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'personalInfo/details.html', {"profile": profile})
```

Now, in the template you can do

```
{{ profile.fullName }}
```

Note that the capitalisation is important. If you have `fullName` in your model, then `profile.fullname` will not work in the template. Note that the recommended style in for field names in Django is `lowercase_with_underscores`, i.e. `full_name`.

Comment: You my friend, are a genius. Thank you :D